# I want to Bind results data of linq query to list box or long list Using Parse Object

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need some help from you about my WP8 App .I want to Bind results data of linq query to list box or long list

**error message is**

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object' ''StartOptionsViewModel' (HashCode=7730701)'. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayName; DataItem='StartOptionsViewModel' (HashCode=7730701); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

**here is my Code**

```
public async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = from Item in ParseObject.GetQuery("Item")
                orderby Item.CreatedAt descending
                select Item;
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
    foreach (var Item in results)
    {
        ItemName = Item["itemName"] as string;
        Debug.WriteLine(ItemName);
    }
}

 public string ItemName { get; set; }
```

I hope you can help me

Thanks....

Comment: post relevant portion of your XAML. Where is 'DisplayName' and 'StartOptionsViewModel' that the error message complaining about?

Comment: i have some difficult here because i am using Parse Query how i can write return result of object query property